# Making a drop-right menu on .css file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a drop-right menu bar. Now, I can only move the drop-down menu to the right when hovering over it with `margin-left: 100%;`, but that drop-down menu doesn't move up even though I use `top: 0;`. So it is very confusing to get to the drop-right menu bar in the CSS. If you have any solution please comment. Thank you in advance.

```css
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    
}

ul li{
    float: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    opacity: 0.8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}

ul li a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(97, 98, 99);
}

ul li uL li{
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Living Room</a>
    
        <ul>
      <li>          
         1 : <input type="checkbox" id="index01" class="cm-toggle" onclick="index1()"><br>  
      </li>
      <li>
         2 : <input type="checkbox" id="index02" class="cm-toggle" onclick="index2()"><br>
      </li>
      <li>
         3 : <input type="checkbox" id="index03" class="cm-toggle" onclick="index3()"><br>
      </li>
      <li>
         4 : <input type="checkbox" id="index04" class="cm-toggle" onclick="index4()"><br>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "top" property needs a position property to be applied. A position like "relative", "absolute", "fixed", or "sticky". So, if you aim to use "top" here, you can add these two rules:

```
        ul > li {
      position: relative;
    } 

    ul li ul {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
```

And the code will work fine.

```css
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    
}

ul li{
    float: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    opacity: 0.8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}

ul li a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(97, 98, 99);
}

ul li uL li{
    display: none;
}

ul > li {
  position: relative;
} 

ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

ul li:hover ul li{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Living Room</a>
      
          <ul>
        <li>          
           1 : <input type="checkbox" id="index01" class="cm-toggle" onclick="index1()"><br>  
        </li>
        <li>
           2 : <input type="checkbox" id="index02" class="cm-toggle" onclick="index2()"><br>
        </li>
        <li>
           3 : <input type="checkbox" id="index03" class="cm-toggle" onclick="index3()"><br>
        </li>
        <li>
           4 : <input type="checkbox" id="index04" class="cm-toggle" onclick="index4()"><br>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Also, you can use "margin-top" instead of "top" by applying a negative margin to the top of the child "ul". The value of the margin should be the same as the "a" height, which you specified as 40px.

```
ul li{
    float: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px; /* same like this */
    background-color: darkgrey;
    opacity: 0.8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li ul {
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Here is the full code snippet:

```css
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    
}

ul li{
    float: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px; /* same like this */
    background-color: darkgrey;
    opacity: 0.8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li ul {
  margin-top: -40px;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}

ul li a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(97, 98, 99);
}

ul li uL li{
    display: none;
} 

ul li:hover ul li{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Living Room</a>
      
          <ul>
        <li>          
           1 : <input type="checkbox" id="index01" class="cm-toggle" onclick="index1()"><br>  
        </li>
        <li>
           2 : <input type="checkbox" id="index02" class="cm-toggle" onclick="index2()"><br>
        </li>
        <li>
           3 : <input type="checkbox" id="index03" class="cm-toggle" onclick="index3()"><br>
        </li>
        <li>
           4 : <input type="checkbox" id="index04" class="cm-toggle" onclick="index4()"><br>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it is very clear.

Comment: I'm glad to help you.

Comment: By the way, just a quick question. Is it possible to create a drop-right in the drop-down and then in the drop-down again and so on? Is there a limit number drop-down function on this coding technique?

Comment: No limits. But you need to make a small edit to the style. For example, if you choose the "top" approach, then you need to make sure the "relative" is applied on the parent ul only (or the li inside it since there's no other li inside it). second, you need to adapt the last CSS rule in the above snippet to be like "ul > li:hover > ul > li" to make sure that the opening functionality won't happen until the user hovers on the target parent. You can check https://jsfiddle.net/pdzt7aeo/ for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use position: absolute before using top :0%;

add to your CSS in the ul :

```
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;

}
```